# Performing rails query with mysql with backslash in string

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a database entry that looks like the following:

name = `servername\vs1`

We have a search that is looking for this term.

```
  scope :search, ->(term) {
    if term
      where('name LIKE ?', "%#{term}%")
    else
      all
    end
  }
```

However, it isn't finding it.  When someone searches for `severname`, of course, it shows up.  But when they include the **backslash** it isn't found.

After doing some research, I found that rails is currently adding a single backslash to the query term prior to search (`servername\\vs1`) but mysql needs the following format: (`servername\\\\vs1`).

So, I was hoping there was an easy rails way to add additional backslashes.  Looking for any good solution.

Thanks

Comment: Try `"#{sanitize("%#{term}%")}"`

Comment: @MrYoshiji almost! It's adding single quotes around the string.  getting the following:  `"'servername\\\\vs1'"`

Comment: What about `where("name LIKE #{sanitize("%#{term}%")}")` (don't worry about SQL injections, `sanitize` protects you here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest to use Arel, like this:

```
  scope :search, ->(term){
    t = arel_table
    term ? where( t[:name].matches("%#{term}%") )
         : all
  }
```

Example:

```
Simple.search('\a').to_sql
"SELECT \"simples\".* FROM \"posts\"  WHERE (\"simples\".\"title\" LIKE '%\\a%')"
```